# Can you stream music from an iPhone to an iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, music, streaming

I'm playing with the idea of installing an iPad in my car.

Ideally, I'd like to save the storage space for video and buy a smaller model, so I'm wondering if there is a way to play the music I have on my iPhone on an iPad via streaming or an app or other means?

Comment: found http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pairshare/id424429744?mt=8&ls=1# (pairshare) recently. wouldn't use the music app unfortunately, but looks to be a viable option.

Comment: tried out pairshare. decent, but not usable for me. maxes at 1000 songs. doesn't use the music app (expected). pretty primitive playback...no shuffle, can only organize by song title (not by band, album, etc.), doesn't save the 'shared' songs...nice app but just not there yet. also it's iphones-sized on the ipad, so not very visually appealing.

Answer (score 1):

If your iPad is a 3G/Wi-Fi model, then you could conceivably do this through the music app. The reason for the need for 3G is that in order to connect these devices there must be some sort of network present.

That being said, this seems like overkill. If you are using your iPad for music and only music in the car, and if you have the means and desire to pull this off, then I would strongly suggest you simply get a car stereo with a 1/8" input auxiliary jack.  This would allow you to plug the iPhone directly into your car stereo, without any other hassle.

Furthermore, streaming data like this is a good way to unnecessarily rack up data usage charges, as you would be transmitting data 100% of the time. Go with the plug-n-play solution: you stream no data at all.

Seriously think about this. Again, it seems a bit like overkill.

Comment: ideally, the solution would involve bluetooth so there'd be no cost to the data transfer. but calling it overkill is subjective and unhelpful. plug and play solution? well considering i'm asking about playing music from an iphone on an ipad, what plug and play solution do you suggest? again, i'm not asking how to connect a iphone to a car.

Comment: Fair enough: "overkill" might be a subjective appraisal. Assuming it's not (from your perspective), then what advantage are you gaining from using all the potential that is an iPad as the receiver/intermediary between an iPhone and a stereo? I pose this question to you with all helpfulness intended. The plug and play solution I mentioned was getting a car stereo head with the auxiliary input. Additionally, Bluetooth, as far as I know, is not capable of creating a network that would allow streaming of music. Sorry if this isn't more helpful, but the answer isn't always related to the question.

Comment: lot of reasons. 1. gorgeous ui/ux. 2. movies 3. big screen 4. flexibility...i can take the device in and out of the vehicle. on the other hand, comprable head units have horrible ui (both in terms of ux and just visually), are just as expensive if not more so, and don't offer any of the flexibility--you're using it anywhere but in the car.

Comment: I understand. It sounds like you have a lot of advantages in mind that were not conveyed in your original post. You might consider restating your post, because when you say: "playing with the idea of installing an ipad in my car," you are insinuating a very different idea than what you've just posted in your comment. For example, I interface my iPod with my car stereo, but that does not mean I installed the iPod. To your original question: I still offer that you can easily stream music over 3G in the car using the Music app. You cannot do this with Bluetooth, though.